# Macro (excel_mac) Transfer data from a table to another and add a line after

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to create a macro that will, after each execution, change the range of where it will be transfered.

This is my code right now (no idea how to change the line after each exe):

```
Sheets("Suivi").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Rapport").Select
    Range("I6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to start here: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ)

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you are just trying to fill up column I, you probably want to use something like:

```
With Sheets("Rapport")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Sheets("Suivi").Range("B3").Value
End With
```

---

Note: This will work on Windows, but I don't know about in the Mac version.  (But it is so basic that I can't really imagine that the two versions won't cater for this in the same way.)

Comment: I don't know if I misused your code because whenever I re-run the macro it writes over the old data. I'm trying to keep every data transfered that way. Here is what my code :
`Sheets("Suivi").Select

With Sheets("Rapport")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Sheets("Suivi").Range("B3").Value

    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Rapport").Select
    Range("H6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False
End With`

Comment: If you want to copy to the next available cell in column H of sheet Rapport, get rid of **everything** you just pasted into your comment (the `Offset(-1, 0)` is especially wrong) and replace it with the code in my answer, except changing my `"I"` to `"H"`.